# How to include ' partition by ' in TD15 Pivot function?

Tags: pivot, teradata

Right now I'm having query like this -

```
SELECT a, b, 
       SUM (CASE WHEN measure_name = 'ABC' THEN measure_qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b )  AS   ABCPIVOT          
FROM data_app.work_test
```

Now as TD15 is supporting direct PIVOTING.
How do I include this partition by in PIVOT function?

Comment: PIVOT is aggregating, but you're doing *Windowed Aggregates*. And even if there was a way to PIVOT it will not improve performance (PIVOT is rewritten to SUM/MAX/Etc. over CASE internally).

Comment: Over a huge dataset it should improve the performance I think. As TD15 is supporting PIVOT , I was curious if there's any way of replacing the case statement with PIVOT. I couldn't find any docs related to including the partition by option .

Comment: As I wrote, PIVOT is internally rewritten using MAX over CASE, thus performance will be exactly the same. And it can't be used with OVER.